# redirect and rewrite url using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently I was thinking of making some seo friendly urls by rewrite and redirecting urls.

the rule which I wrote is working fine for this type of url like `xyz.com/abc.php` this automatically got converted into `xyz.com/abc` now I need help with this type of urls `abc.com/study.php/abc/123` which I want to redirect on `abc.com/study/abc/123`

my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

**EDIT**.

It was working fine now I have changed my mind that instead of removing .php extension from all files I want to remove .php extension specifically from 2 files i.e `a.php` and `b.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your existing rules to support this `PATH_INFO` as well like this:

```
# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s/+(\S+?)\.php(/\S*)?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)(/.*)?$ /$1.php$2 [L]
```

Comment: what if only want to remove .php extension specifically from two files i.e `a.php` and `b.php` instead of removing from all files

Comment: Replace `(\S+?)` in 1st rule and `(.+?)` in 2nd rule with `(a|b)`

Comment: if I need to apply same rule again on a.php and b.php but this time their location is in c directory like `/c/a.php and /c/b.php` instead of root directory `/`,I tried placing .htaccess in that directory but its not working

Comment: Try last rule as: `RewriteRule ^/?(a|b)(/.*)?$ /c/$1.php$2 [L]`